# Android WebView: loading a local HTML file ignoring its body

Tags: android, html, webview, loading

I would like to know if it is possible to load a local HTML file into a WebView loading everything but the body innerHTML. That is, the resulting DOM will have head, scripts and CSS's but the body will be empty. I tried emptying the body just after loadUrl call but the WebViews goes on loading the body. I want the body is not loaded at all so to speed up loading, that is, no rendering has to be done by the WebView.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack by why not try this:

```
String html = loadHtmlFromFile();
String newHtml = html.replaceFirst("<body>.*<\body>", "<body><\body>");
```

This will replace the body with just the body tags.

Then either save `newHtml` as an html file and open that or, if possible, pass the HTML directly to the `WebView` (although I'm not sure you can do that)

You'll also have to write the `loadHtmlFromFile()` method to get your HTML for you.

Comment: Your trick is useful (I knew it) but it doesn't take into account for possible differences in writing the body outerHTML like < body> or <body > or < body style='zoom=0.5'> and so on

Comment: True. If you wanted to get around that you could try use an XML parser to load the html, and then remove all the children of the body element. I can post an XML parser example if you want. This assumes you're writing good, validated XHTML though